# Last Sealing on Hoshana Rabba or Shmini Atzeret?

Tags: sources-mekorot, chagim-holidays, hoshana-rabbah, shmini-atzeres

I have heard in numerous Shiurim that one is judged on Rosh ha Shana, sealed on Yom Kippur and finally sealed on...

- A) Shmini Atzeret
- B) The night of Hoshana Rabba
- C) The day of Hoshana Rabba.

What do the sources that talk about that actually say ?

Comment: Don't forget about zos chanukah.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer in this
[article published by Yeshivat Ohr Sameyach](https://ohr.edu/this_week/seasons__then_and_now/8567)

*"The deeper sources add that the judgment still continues until Shemini Atzeret. According to these sources, on Rosh Hashana one is judged and his verdict is written, on Yom Kippur his verdict is sealed, and at midnight on Hoshana Rabba his verdict is sealed with an additional outer seal, and the papers containing his verdict are given over to the messengers who will carry them out. These messengers though are not allowed to carry out the verdict until Shemini Atzeret (see Shlah, Masechet Succah, Perek Torah Ohr 70, Ben Ish Chai I V’zot Habracha 2 and Kaf HaChaim 664:1-5, 18-19 who quote the Zohar and the Arizal).*

In another  [image: article] the Arizal is being quoted saying that the Judgment is send on Shmini Atzeret during the time of the Kedusha of the Mussaf prayer.

*****Means that we have 3 times:*****

**Midnight Hoshana Rabba: Final Sealing**

**Midnight Hoshana Rabba-Mussaf Kedusha Shmini Atzeret: In between time

Mistama time for teshuva**

**Mussaf Kedusha Shmini Atzeret: The beginning of the judgements exercising**

Comment: Very moved reading this. Very relevant

Comment: Maybe turn the picture into text

Comment: Yes... this year we really felt the judgment coming down.

Comment: I just read that the power of Ishmael ( who is supposed to rule over Eretz Israel for 9 months before mashiach comes) can be destroyed through tfilla! Davon! Davon! Davon!